# Making Multiple Cubes from Looping Through getImageData pixel color data in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas, getimagedata

I uses a simple 3x3.png file to retrieve the color/opacity data from. (each of the 9 pixels are a different color/opacity).

The .png is loaded and supposed to be in an off-screen separate canvas then the 9 cubes are supposed to be drawn in a 3x3 formation.

I think this is really close to working, but obviously something is wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>a png made into cubes per pixel</title>
<style>body {margin: 0px;background-color: #99F;overflow: hidden;}</style>
<script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- the 3x3 png image pre-loading -->
<img id='image1' src='3x3.png' onload="javascript:loaded();">
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>


<script>
    function loaded(){

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = document.getElementById("image1").src;
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    camera.position.z = 5;
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );

    for (ix = 0; ix < img.width; ix++) { 
        for (iy = 0; iy < img.height; iy++) { 
            // get next pixel data
            var data = ctx.getImageData( ix, iy, 1, 1 ).data;
            var floats = data.slice( 0, 4 ).map( function( val ) { return val / 255; });
            var computedcolor = THREE.Color( floats[0], floats[1], floats[2] );
            var computedopacity = floats[4];

            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: computedcolor, opacity: computedopacity, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( cube );
            cube.position.x = ix; //move the cube positions to rebuild the image using cubes instead of pixels
            cube.position.y = iy;
        }
    }

    var render = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame( render );
        camera.position.z = camera.position.z + .01;
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    render();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _I think this is really close to working, but obviously something is wrong_. Please, describe you problem: how can you say _something is wrong_?

Comment: When this page loads in Chrome, the top 1/4 of the window shows the html output containing the small 3 pixel square png image, and the remaining 3/4 of the page shows the canvas with nothing in it.

Comment: I think the two problems are perhaps the method to preload the image data, then with drawing the 9 cubes in the for-loop. I've gotten these two examples separately to work but not in this case. - The goal here is to specify an image - in this case 3x3.png then have each pixel be its own cube  THREE.mesh. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var computedopacity = floats[4]` should be `var computedopacity = floats[3]` instead.

However, I don't know if that solves it. Instead of trying to find where the issue is, I've coded what you're trying to do from scratch:

```
function boxelizeImage( image ) {

    // 2D

    var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;

    var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
    context.drawImage( image, 0, 0 );

    var data = context.getImageData( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height ).data;

    // 3D

    var group = new THREE.Group();
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );

    for ( var i = 0, j = 0; i < data.length; i += 4, j ++ ) {

        var color = new THREE.Color();
        color.fromArray( data, i );
        color.multiplyScalar( 1 / 255 );

        if ( color.getHex() === 0 ) continue;

        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
            color: color,
            wireframe: true,
        } );
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        mesh.position.x = j % canvas.width;
        mesh.position.y = - Math.floor( j / canvas.width );
        group.add( mesh );

    }

    return group;

}

//

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 500 );
camera.position.x = 15;
camera.position.y = -10;
camera.position.z = 80;

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var image = new Image();
image.addEventListener( 'load', function () {
    var group = boxelizeImage( image );
    scene.add( group );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
} );
image.src = '../img/logo.png';

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/44mj229c/